# Looking for an invariant

Tags: combinatorics, invariant-theory

To each vertex of a regular pentagon an integer is assigned in such a way that
the sum of all of the five numbers is positive. If three consecutive vertices are assigned
the numbers x, y, z, respectively, and y < 0, then the following operation is allowed:
the numbers x, y, z are replaced by x + y, −y,  z + y, respectively. Such an operation is
performed repeatedly as long as at least one of the five numbers is negative. Determine
whether this procedure necessarily comes to an end after a finite number of steps.

The answer says that it does come to an end after a finite number of steps.

Normally in these type of questions which involve transformations, one would look for an invariant, but I am having trouble in doing so. Is looking for an invariant/semi-invariant the right way to go? Or, is there any other way of looking at it ?

Comment: Hint: When the
operation is performed the quantity decreases by $|x|+|z|−|x+y|−|y+z|$

Comment: I thought for the operation to be allowed $y<0$...

Comment: I haven't understood how you choose the three vertices to which you apply the transform. Is it deterministic ? I mean, if I want to program this, what do I do for  "the next move" ? What is meant by "repeatedly" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the operation is performed the quantity decreases by $|x|+|z|−|x+y|−|y+z|$. The desired semi-invariant should include the absolute values of pairwise sums, sums of triples and foursomes as well. With a
pentagon numbered $v,w, x, y, z$ and the semi-invariant defined by 
$$ S(v,w, x, y, z) = |v| + |w| + |x| + |y| + |z| + |v + w| + |w + x| + |x + y|
+ |y + z| + |z + v| + |v + w + x| + |w + x + y| + |x + y + z|
+ |y + z + v| + |z + v + w| + |v + w + x + y| + |w + x + y + z|
+ |x + y + z + v| + |y + z + v + w| + |z + v + w + x|, $$ it is evident that the operation reduced the value of $S$ by the expression 
$$ |z + v + w +
x| − |z + v + w + x + 2y| = |s − y| − |s + y|,$$
where $$s = v + w + x + y + z $$ 
As $s > 0$ and $y < 0$, it is trivial that $$ |s − y| − |s + y| > 0$$
Thus $S$ is a semi-invariant with the required property. Using the semi-invariant, one can produce a proof by infinite descent.

Comment: So the invariant can be obtained only with some guesswork..

Comment: I'm afraid so. A lot of invariant finding involves intuition/observation and can be proved only later.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the answer (and for the previous one too I just noticed).